# Wagtail API - How to filter by foreign key field, other than primary key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm currently using Wagtail's API. I have the following:

```py
...

@register_snippet
class DocumentCategory(index.Indexed, models.Model):
    """
    Defines a Document category
    """

    # Name of the category
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Nome"),
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
    )

    # String representation of this model
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Categoria de Documento")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Categorias de Documentos")
        ordering = ["name"]  # alphabetical order

class DocumentPage(BasePage):
 """
    Document Page
    """

    # The document
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtaildocs.Document",
        verbose_name=_("Documento"),
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    # Category of the document (only 1 category)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        "document.DocumentCategory",
        verbose_name=_("Categoria"),
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text=_("Categoria do Documento"),
        related_name="document",
    )
```

Let's assume I have a category named `Categoria Doc 1`. How can I hit Wagtail's API to filter based on the foreign key name? I would like to do the following:

```
GET /api/pages/?type=document.DocumentPage&category=Categoria Doc 1
```

However, when I do this, I get the following:
[image]